# GitHub API get issues description using Python

Tags: python-3.x, github-api, github3.py

The task: (using GitHub API) 
1) get all closed milestones for a given repo
2) get all issues for that milestone
3) for every issue get it's description
4) finally, using Markdown for example, create a page for PM to view

I'm using Python 3.5, using lib github3.py, I got 1&2 but having trouble with #3.
Looking at the GitHub documents, I'm not sure it supports retrieving the description of an issue.

I'm looking at this API document:
https://developer.github.com/v3/issues

My question is, can #3 be done? Am I missing anything?

Thank you. What I have so far is this:

```
g = github3.login(token='123...')
r = g.repository(owner='owner', repository='services')
for m in r.milestones(state='closed'):
    print(m.as_json()) # this works giving me all the milestones
for i in r.issues(milestone=5, state='closed'):
    print(i.pull_request()) # works giving me all the pull requests from here
```

Comment: Could you share the code of #3 ?

Comment: g = github3.login(token='123...')
r = g.repository(owner='owner', repository='services')
for m in r.milestones(state='closed'):
    print(m.as_json()) # this works giving me all the milestones

for i in r.issues(milestone=5, state='closed'):
    print(i.pull_request())  # works giving me all the pull requests

from here I need the description of each pull request.

ignore the sloppy code please I'm still in the learning phase.

Answer (score 2):

So the description of an issue is typically returned from the API in the `body` portion of the object.

The problem you *might* have (I haven't exercised this path before) is that the body *might not* be returned when you list the issues like that. If that's the case, then you will need to do something like:

```
for m in r.milestones(state='closed'):
    for i in r.issues(milestone=m.number, state='closed'):
         i.refresh()
         print(i.body)
```

It's worth noting, however, that the body you get there will be the body the user entered. If you wan to display it as HTML without rendering, github3.py requests that from the GitHub API for you automatically so then you could instead just access

```
i.body_html
```

Or if you wanted everything in plain-text

```
i.body_text
```

Cheers!

Comment: ok so this seems to be the solution, one thing before I confirm it.
if I do milestone=m.id I get an error:

raise exceptions.error_for(response)
github3.exceptions.UnprocessableEntity: 422 Validation Failed

for it to work, I did milestones=5 for example, then I get exactly what I need.
I could of course parse the m.json() to get the int required, is there anything else I can do other than m.id?

Comment: Sorry. I always get that confused. It's not `m.id` it's `m.number`.